# <h:commandButton> doesn't start the action - NO IDEA?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to use **dataModel** instead of binding dataTable and have this issue. At the last column there is a commandButton which should be used for delete item from database. But when I press it, the java method isn't started.

**Part of xhtml (reduced code):**

```
<h:form>
<rich:extendedDataTable 
  id="table"
  var="fItem"  
  value="#{myFood.model}" 
  selectionMode="none">

 <rich:column width="150px">
  <f:facet name="header">Datum:</f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{fItem.date}"/>
 </rich:column>

 <rich:column>
    <h:commandButton id="save" action="#{myFood.delete}" value="delete"/>
 </rich:column>

 <f:facet name="footer">  
   <h:commandButton id="btnTest" action="#{myFood.test}" value="test"/>
 </f:facet>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
</h:form>
```

**Part of MyFood.java:**

```
public void delete()
{
  System.out.println("TEST");
  try 
  {
    DaoCrud.delete(model.getRowData(), 'P');
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {.....}
}

public void test()
{
  System.out.println("TEST");
}
```

But even "TEST" is not writen to console! 
Where could be the problem?

**UPDATE:** I've updated code examples (facet & test()), it works. Everything works fine until I've tried using dataModel `private DataModel<Item> model;`...
When I simply move the same commandButton to the facet, it works.

Comment: What JEE server are you using? Under some environments `System.out.println` does not work. Does using that to print messages work elsewhere?

Comment: I'm using tomcat7, but when I place the commandButton to the faces It works normally...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by _when I place the commandButton to the faces It works normally_... Are you saying that in some other circumstances the logging works? Or the button works?

Comment: I've update my post. CommandButton at facet normally calls test() method and "TEST" is written to console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bean is request scoped, then you need to ensure that **exactly the same** model is been created during bean's (post)construction of the form submit request as it was during displaying the initial form.

```
private List<Item> list;
private DataModel<Item> model;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    list = itemService.list();
    model = new ListDataModel<Item>(list);
}
```

JSF will namely iterate over the model during the apply request values phase to determine the button pressed so that it can be invoked during the invoke application phase.

If preserving the model in the subsequent request isn't exactly trivial due to some business restrictions (e.g. missing parameters, etc), then you need to put the bean in the view scope by marking it [`@ViewScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) instead of `@RequestScoped`. This works only if you're using JSF 2.0.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {}
```

Alternatively, since you're using RichFaces, you could also use [`<a4j:keepAlive>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_keepAlive.html) for this. Put this somewhere in the same page as the form:

```
<a4j:keepAlive beanName="#{myBean}" />
```

This does effectively the same as `@ViewScoped` does in JSF 2.0.

Comment: Thank you, BalusC, I'll try it, but could you explain this? list = itemService.list();

Comment: It was just an example to fill the list. You can do whatever way you use to fill the list. But it should happen right there.

Comment: BalusC, don´t you have some working example? Maybe I'm little bit slowly, but first issue is "<a4j:keepAlive> Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/a4j, but no tag was defined for name: keepAlive" and the second "java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.model.ListDataModel"......... It's not neccessary for me, but it's strange it doesn't work :)

Comment: Oh, that tag has been removed in RF 4.0 in favour of the view scope. As to the datamodel, mark it `transient` and lazily instantiate it in the getter. Some containers / webapp configs store sessions on disk instead of memory, then the view/session scoped objects needs to implement `Serializable`.

Comment: Aha, i've tried the transient before, but without lazy getter instantiate. Now it's working, alhought I must say, don't understand why:) Thank you!

Comment: I just rewrote the article http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html to explain the need for serialization.

Answer (score 1):

It should be under `<h:form>`

Answer (score 1):

Your `delete()` method should return an Object. It won't be called if the signature is not correct. "signature must match java.lang.Object action()". See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/commandButton.html).

As far as I remember you can just return `null` if you want to stay at the page.

```
public String delete()
{
    System.out.println("TEST");
    try 
    {
       DaoCrud.delete(model.getRowData(), 'P');
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {.....}
    return null;
}
```

You might want to use the `actionListener` attribute with its corresponding method if you dont want to use the method outcome for navigation. Also consider to use a `<a4j:commandButton>` if you want to reRender something after the `actionListener` has been executed.

Comment: Thanks, but the String output doesn't help. I'm using it without redirection and in facet the button works normally...

Comment: Can you show the code where it works? Where in the facets is the button and how does the bean method look like? If the signature is not correct it should not work...

Comment: Hmm, did you try to change the signature and it did not help?

Comment: Rename the method? Yes, nothing happened  :(